# Executing System commands in Java is printing it to console

Tags: java

I am creating a server/client application, where the client can send system commands.

```
// Server Side
// command can be *nix/Windows system commands
public void run() {
  while(true) {
    try {    
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
  }
}
```

`command` is sent from client, and by executing it, in console it wont execute the command but just print it. So if `command = "echo Hello"`, output in console(server side) will be `echo Hello` instead of just `Hello`.

Which method should I use to execute system command ?

Comment: Don't catch and swallow your exception as `catch (Exception e) {}`. Print it like `e.printStacktrace();` There may be process/exec errors and you can find them in exception stacktrace.

Comment: @BimaleshJha I have a line of try/catch errors in actual code, for the sake of code completion I just closed it with a blank catch block.

Comment: @user88975: then you obviously got the error saying that "Cannot run program "echo": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified" - why not tell us that?

Answer (score 0):

`cmd /C echo hello`

echo is not a known/normal Windows executables but a cmd.exe input command.

Comment: Am running this on a mac, now. Tried with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C " + command);` but its justs prints it. This is being executed on a thread, does it have to do anything with this issue ?

Comment: No, the thread has nothing to do with it. I assumed you were on Windows. I supposed it's a bash command you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this could be dump the client sent commands to a temp file (assuming) Linux like `/tmp/some_cmds.sh` and use `bash` to execute it e.g.`/usr/bin/sh /tmp/some_cmds.sh`. Then use java `ProcessBuilder` API to execute the shell with argument as temp file. You can redirect the `stdout` and `stderr` to appropriate files and then send it back to the client as command output.

**NOTE: This method is not portable across OS and it is dangerous too as hackers can potentially run arbitrary cmds from the client on your server.**